# Does Ask Ubuntu support the unity webapps feature?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am hoping [omgubuntu.co.uk](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/) while writing this aricle [list of websites that supports unity's webapps feature](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/list-of-that-websites-support-unitys-new-web-apps-feature) they simply forgot to put askubuntu on that list.... but just in case

**does [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) support unity's webapps feature?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At this time it does not, but it really really should. That being said it should be almost trivial to write in Ask Ubuntu web-apps support for Ask Ubuntu and the other Stack Exchange sites. Either via a greasemonkey script and including it in the OS, or by having the SE team write it in to the site. I'm fairly certain that we can produce a script to be included in the package, but it might be worth seeking out help from the SE devs to just have it included in the site.