# Will Ask Ubuntu become a Unity WebApp?

Tags: feature-request, webapps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Ask Ubuntu support the unity webapps feature?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4102/does-ask-ubuntu-support-the-unity-webapps-feature)

One of the new features in Ubuntu 12.10 is [WebApp support](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/unity-webapps-available-in-ubuntu-1210.html) for certain websites. In this way, sites can be pulled up in the dash like regular applications and gain integration with the default Unity shell.

Are there any plans to add support for this feature to Ask Ubuntu?